# Unable to print the $length variable? Trying to input data from cloned forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

My code is below. I am have arrays declared in html input tag name field, title[], first_name[], last_name[], email_address[], twitter_handle[].
I have declared them all arrays for the sake of form cloning that I am doing in .js file.
Now, I am trying to enter the data from form in to database.
I am using the foreach to manage the arrays, I also took a $length variable which will give me the number of form cloning worked. 
No matter how many times I clone the form, only the first form gets printed.
Please help.
My code is below:

```
    if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email_address']) && isset($_POST['twitter_handle'])){

    $length=0;
   foreach($_POST['title'] as $key=>$value){
      $title[$key]=$value;
      $length=$length + 1;
      echo '$key: '.$key.' '.$length;
      //print_r($value);
    }    

    foreach($_POST['first_name'] as $key=>$value){
      $first_name[$key]=$value;
    }

    foreach($_POST['last_name'] as $key=>$value){
      $last_name[$key]=$value;
    }  

    foreach($_POST['email_address'] as $key=>$value){
      $email_address[$key]=$value;
    }

    foreach($_POST['twitter_handle'] as $key=>$value){
      $twitter_handle[$key]=$value;
    }

    echo '$lenght : '.$length.' ';

    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
      print_r($first_name[$i]);
    }     

   }
```

..................
Just for reference this is my html code:

```
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" id="sign-up_area" role="form">
<label class="label_ttl control-label" for="title">Title:</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="select_ttl form-control" name="title[]" id="title">
              <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select your title</option>
              <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
              <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
              <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
              <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
              <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
            </select> 
          </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label_fn control-label" for="first_name">First name:</label>
          <input id="first_name" name="first_name[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control" required>
          <p class="help-block">This field is required.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label_ln control-label" for="last_name">Last name:</label>
          <input id="last_name" name="last_name[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_ln form-control">
        </div>

         <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label_email control-label" for="email_address">Email:</label>
          <input id="email_address" name="email_address[]" type="text" placeholder="example@example.com" class="input_email form-control">
        </div>

        <!-- Prepended text-->
        <label class="label_twt control-label" for="institution">Enter Institution / Organization:</label>
        <div class="input-group form-group">

          <input id="twitter_handle" name="twitter_handle[]" class="input_twt form-control" placeholder="" type="text">
        </div>
        <!-- Text input-->



        </div><!-- end #entry1 -->
        <!-- Button (Double) -->
        <p>
        <button type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-info">add section</button>
          <button type="button" id="btnDel" name="btnDel" class="btn btn-danger">remove section above</button>
        </p>





        <!-- Button -->
        <p>
          <button id="submit_button" name="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </p>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($_POST['first_name'])` and post the output? I suspect theres only one entry in your array.

Comment: This code only sends one entry. Where is your repetition?

Comment: Yes I only get one entry. I dont know how to put repetition, can help me with repetition please.

Comment: I am under the impression that foreach with run every time I clone the form.
sorry I am a newbie

Comment: @MrGlass this is what I get after vardump($_POST['first_name']) :: 
array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "firstone" }

Comment: Yeah, you only have 1 form, so theres only one entry, so theres only one thing to print out.

Comment: @MrGlass Can you help with the repetition loop please? thanks

Comment: @MrGlass are you there..?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you need help printing the form multiple times?

Comment: Ok, let me try to reiterate the problem:
1. I am using the cloned forms in html.
2. I want to take the input from the clone form fields and enter them in to the database.
3. In the php code above I am trying to fetch the values from html cloned form, and try to print it before I can try to insert it in to the database.
I ultimately will be inserting the values in to database but before that I am trying to print on screen so that I am sure that my php code is fetching all the values from the cloned forms.

@MrGlass thanks for taking time for me. Please try to help.

Comment: @AryaSingh I have never heard of 'cloned' forms before. Do you have any documentation on them? To me, it looks like you are only printing one input form.

Comment: Yes, this is reference link: 
http://tristandenyer.com/using-jquery-to-duplicate-a-section-of-a-form-maintaining-accessibility/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['first_name']) && isset($_POST['last_name']) && isset($_POST['email_address']) && isset($_POST['twitter_handle'])){

  $length=0;
  foreach($_POST['title'] as $key=>$value){
  $title[$key]=$value;
  $length = $length + 1;
  //echo '$key: '.$key.' '.$length;
  //print_r($value);
}    

foreach($_POST['first_name'] as $key=>$value){
  $first_name[$key]=$value;
}

foreach($_POST['last_name'] as $key=>$value){
  $last_name[$key]=$value;
}  

foreach($_POST['email_address'] as $key=>$value){
  $email_address[$key]=$value;
}

foreach($_POST['twitter_handle'] as $key=>$value){
  $twitter_handle[$key]=$value;
}

echo '$lenght : '.$length.' ';

for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
  echo ($first_name[$i])."<br/>";
}   

   }
    ?>
    <head>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   </head>
    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" id="sign-up_area" role="form">
    <div class="form" id="form_1">
    <label class="label_ttl control-label" for="title">Title:</label>
       <div class="form-group">
         <select class="select_ttl form-control" name="title[]" id="title">
          <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select your title</option>
          <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
          <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
          <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
          <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
          <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
        </select> 
        </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label_fn control-label" for="first_name">First name:</label>
      <input id="first_name" name="first_name[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control" required>
      <p class="help-block">This field is required.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label_ln control-label" for="last_name">Last name:</label>
      <input id="last_name" name="last_name[]" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_ln form-control">
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="label_email control-label" for="email_address">Email:</label>
      <input id="email_address" name="email_address[]" type="text" placeholder="example@example.com" class="input_email form-control">
    </div>

    <!-- Prepended text-->
    <label class="label_twt control-label" for="institution">Enter Institution / Organization:</label>
    <div class="input-group form-group">

      <input id="twitter_handle" name="twitter_handle[]" class="input_twt form-control" placeholder="" type="text">
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->



    </div><!-- end #entry1 -->
    <!-- Button (Double) -->
    <p>
    <button type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-info">add section</button>
      <button type="button" id="btnDel" name="btnDel" class="btn btn-danger">remove section above</button>
    </p>





    <!-- Button -->
    <p>
      <button id="submit_button" name="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </p>

    </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnAdd').click(function(){
    var form_length = $(".form").length;
    $('#form_'+form_length).clone().prop({ id: "form_"+parseInt(form_length+1)}).insertAfter('#form_'+form_length);
});
$('#btnDel').click(function(){
    var form_length = $(".form").length;
    if(form_length == 1){
        alert("One form must exist!");
    }else{
        $('.form').last().remove();         
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: it work to an extent, after first clone, when you try third time it gives out 6 clone forms instead of just one clone

Comment: my mistake, I just clone it. I'll edit it with a fix for that.

Comment: @AryaSingh check now is that ok. I fix adding forms, and make a check so you can't delete form if there is only one form on page.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are awesome. It helped me a lot. working fine after your edit. Thanks.